# How to make a custom HeaderTitle in React Navigation Stacknavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Everytime i try to set a custom header in stacknavigation the error appears: "cant find variable View". When i replace the component with just a text, it works.

Error appears everytime i use the class "LogoTitle" for the headerTitel

tryied to use a const insted of a class, but dosent worked

```
const TabNavigation = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({

  AllChats: { screen: AllChatsScreen, 
      navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: "Chats",}}});

class LogoTitle extends React.Component {
  render() {
return (
  <Image
    source={require('./spiro.jpg')}
    style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}/>);}}

const SignedInn = createStackNavigator({
  TabNavigation: {
screen: TabNavigation,
  },},{
  navigationOptions: {
headerTitle: <LogoTitle/>}})

export const createRootNavigator = (signedIn = false) => {
  return createSwitchNavigator(
{
  SignedIn: {
    screen: SignedInn}});};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use header instead of headerTitle to be able to use View

```
const SignedIn = createStackNavigator ({
  TabNavigation:{screen: TabNavigation,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: <LogoTitle navigation= {navigation} />,
    })
  },
})
```

Comment: Yeah i tryied that, but the error "cant find variable Image" in LogoTitle still appears.  But i dont know why he thinks <Image> in the render is a variable

Comment: have you declared Image inside 'react-native'? and don't forget to wrap your Image inside View

Comment: oh got it. i done a mistake there. i separated the code and forgot to declare Image etc. Thanks fr your help!